# ubuntu 12.04 does not see cd/dvd burner

Tags: virtualbox

I have just recently installer Oracle VM VirtualBox version 4.2.18 on 64 bit windows 8 machine as HOST to carry ubuntu 12.04 as GUEST. All went well until I tried to install K3b and Brasero burning programs and BOTH programs do not "see" my cd/dvd burner/player. This is very distressing for me as I do a lot of burning. I have scoured the net for a solution but all to no avail. Can anyone out there help me?????

Comment: What are the optical drive settings for the vm?

Comment: What content is it you try to burn on CD/DVD?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a drive defined in VirtualBox.

In VirtualBox Manager window, click on Settings, and then click on Storage

[image]

Under storage Tree click on the CD icon, and then choose a CD drive to use with VirtualBox.

[image]

Comment: Hello Mitch,thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately my storage tree shows that my CD drive is not empty.It shows having "VBoxGuestAdditions.iso" in there when in fact the drive is empty.

Comment: VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is a virtual image.  Once installed, it will no longer show.  When you click on the little CD con, what do you have listed there?

Comment: Hello again Mitch, when I click on the little CD icon I now see listed 'Host Drive 'F'. Kind Regards Bryan